# Ruby/Rails collect value from database with id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, rails-activerecord

Trying to teach myself Rails and have come across something that was easy in PHP but have got confused and stuck on this one area.

I have a form with a number of drop downs. I have managed to get the drop downs to display a value and store the id of that value into another table. Now I would like to view the new record but instead of displaying the ID that I saved I would like to collect the value from the original table and display that.

I hope that makes sense.

Below is my current code.

**Finding Model**

```
class Finding < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :skill
```

**Skill Model**

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :skill_desc, :skill_level
has_many :findings
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<td>Finding Skill</td>
<td><%= @finding.skill_id %> </td>
```

I guess my question is what do I need to change the @finding.skill_id too, to show the skill_desc field from the skills model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= @finding.skill.skill_desc %>
```

`@finding.skill` returns the `Skill` object associated with that finding, upon which you can call `skill_desc` to retrieve said value.

Answer (score 1):

```
@finding.skill.skill_desc
```

If you wanted to find the findings of a skill, you would need to use

`@skill.findings` to return an array of the findings objects associated with that skill object.

In sql, it might look something like this

```
SELECT * FROM findings WHERE ID EQ 23 JOIN skills ON findings.skill_id = Skills.id
```